# If x4 has high negative correlation with x1 - x3, which all correlate highly with each other, will x4 also be difficult to estimate in a regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Say you have predictor variables x1 through x4 and response y. x1, x2, x3 all highly correlate with each other, thus they will have inflated standard errors due to that multicollinearity. Meanwhile x4 has a very high negative correlation with x1 - x3. My question is, will x4 also have an inflated standard error?

Note that my response y has high positive correlation with x1 - x3, and high negative correlation with x4. I understand x1-x3 may not be significant due to multicollinearity, but I still figured x4 would have a significant negative coefficient. But for my data, it does not (unless I remove one or two of the other xs).

I thought maybe an analogy could be: we can't tell what the cause is (i.e. assign coefficients) of your obesity (y) because we don't know whether it's due to eating lots of unhealthy foods (x1 - x3) or if it's because you don't eat enough healthy food (x4).

Comment: Answer: use `-x4` as a predictor instead.

Comment: ^If the true driver of y is actually x1-x3 though, then x4 would have a significant coefficient when in fact it has nothing to do with y.

Comment: That's correct.  My suggestion separates that issue from the issue of *negative* correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for how much the standard error is inflated depends on $R^2$, so the sign of $r$ doesn't matter. "negative" correlation is the same as "regular" correlation when it comes to multicollinearity. What matter is how close the features are to being linearly depending, and a feature with a correlation of -1 is just as linearly dependent as one with a correlation of +1.

Comment: got it, after looking up the VIF formula that makes sense!